# Garbage collection for a simple python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am writing a python class like this:

```
class MyImageProcessor:
   def __init__ (self, image, metadata):
     self.image=image
     self.metadata=metadata
```

Both `image` and `metadata` are objects of a class written by a
colleague. Now I need to  make sure there is no waste of memory.  I am thinking of defining a `quit()` method like this,

```
  def quit():
    self.image=None
    self.metadata=None
    import gc
    gc.collect()
```

and suggest users to call `quit()` systematically. I would like to know whether this is the right way. In particular, do the instructions in `quit()` above guarantee that unused memories being well collected?

Alternatively, I could rename quit() to the build-in `__exit__()`, and suggest users to use the "with" syntax. But my question is
more about whether the instructions in quit() indeed fulfill the garbage collection work one would need in this situation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: doesn't the gc module automatically collect by default?

Comment: There's no need to implement your own form on RAII. Once all references to `image` and `metadata` no longer exist, the gc will automatically remove them from memory. If `image` and `metadata` are only referenced in `MyImageProcessor`, then all you need to do is make sure instances of `MyImageProcessor` don't live for longer than they need to (e.g. by adding them to a list or dict or something and never removing them). Once it goes out of scope, and there are no remaining references to it, the gc will remove it from memory.

Answer (score 4):

In python every object has a built-in **reference_count**, the variables(names) you create are only pointers to the objects. There are mutable and unmutable variables (for example if you change the value of an integer, the name will be pointed to another integer object, while changing a list element will not cause changing of the list name).

Reference count basically counts how many variable uses that data, and it is incremented/decremented automatically.
The garbage collector will destroy the objects with zero references (actually not always, it takes extra steps to save time). You should check out [this article](https://realpython.com/python-variables/).

Similarly to object constructors (`__init__()`), which are called on object creation, you can define destructors (`__del__()`), which are executed on object deletion (usually when the reference count drops to 0). According to [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/destructors-in-python/), in python *they are not needed as much needed in C++ because Python has a garbage collector that handles memory management automatically.* You can check out those examples too.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

No need for `quit()` (Assuming you're using C-based python).

Python uses two methods of garbage collection, as alluded to in the other answers.

First, there's **reference counting**. Essentially each time you add a reference to an object it gets incremented & each time you remove the reference (e.g., it goes out of scope) it gets decremented.

From https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/:

> When an object’s reference count becomes zero, the object is deallocated. If it contains references to other objects, their reference counts are decremented. Those other objects may be deallocated in turn, if this decrement makes their reference count become zero, and so on.

You can get information about current reference counts for an object using `sys.getrefcount(x)`, but really, why bother.

The second way is through **garbage collection** (`gc`). *[Reference counting  is a type of garbage collection, but python specifically calls this second method "garbage collection" -- so we'll also use this terminology. ]* This is intended to find those places where reference count is not zero, but the object is no longer accessible. ("Reference cycles") For example:

```
class MyObj:
    pass
x = MyObj()
x.self = x
```

Here, `x` refers to itself, so the actual reference count for x is more than 1. You can call `del x` but that merely removes it from your scope: it lives on because "someone" still has a reference to it.

`gc`, and specifically `gc.collect()` goes through objects looking for cycles like this and, when it finds an unreachable cycle (such as your `x` post deletion), it will deallocate the whole lot.

Back to your question: You don't need to have a quit() object because as soon as your `MyImageProcessor` object goes out of scope, it will decrement reference counters for `image` and `metadata`. If that puts them to zero, they're deallocated. If that doesn't, well, someone else is using them.

Your setting them to None first, merely decrements the reference count *right then*, but when `MyImageProcessor` goes out of scope, it won't decrement those reference count again, because MyImageProcessor no longer holds the image or metadata objects! So you're just explicitly doing what python does for you already for free: no more, no less.

You didn't create a cycle, so your calling `gc.collect()` is unlikely to change anything.

Check out https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/ if you are interested in more earthy details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it make sense but to my logic you could

Use :

gc.get_count()

before and after

gc.collect()

to see if something has been removed.

[what are count0, count1 and count2 values returned by the Python gc.get_count()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57462037/what-are-count0-count1-and-count2-values-returned-by-the-python-gc-get-count)